# Webcam Recognized in Some Programs, but Not All (Chrome (Chromium))

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, webcam

I have a miniDV camcorder connected via a Fire Wire cable and I have Windows 10.  Strangely, it's recognized and works fine in some programs, but not others.

Works in....

- FireFox
- Camtasia (screen recording software)

Does NOT work in....

- Chrome (and Edge because Chromium)
- Skype
- Windows Camera app (it alleges that there is not a camera attached... but there is)

[It is also recognized in the Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvYuJ.png)

When I go to https://webcamtests.com/ on FF, I get this [successful result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyer3.png).
When I go to https://webcamtests.com/ on Chrome, I get this [failing result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPLA1.png).

The biggest thing I need is for it to work in Chrome.  Does anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to tell you how to fix it but I can explain why it is happening.

"Windows Camera app alleges that there is no camera attached" because there isn't a "Camera" attached as far as Windows is concerned.  I can tell that by your Device Manager screen shot.

[image: Here is what an actual "Camera" looks like in device manager]

Your device probably reporting itself as USB class 10h (Audio/Video Device) which uses a different protocol to communicate than an actual webcam.  I have seen more scanners show up in this category than cameras and have NO IDEA why (but many do).  My guess is the firmware person was guessing their way through the design (I have been there).  It appears that FireFox and Camtasia know how to deal with class 10h.

> Update: The USB port on your camcorder only allows transfer of still
> images from the memory card or live video.  That is why it is getting
> stuck as a "scanner".  The fireware support does not matter
> even if using fireware.

A "Camera" is a specific USB class 0Eh (Video).

This *might* be because of something happening in the fireware controller but is more likely that it is simply because of the USB class this device is presenting.

Seem stupid?  That is because it is.

Are you able to contact the mfg of the camcorder and ask about a better driver?  They can fake anything out they want at the driver layer.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It's a Canon miniDV camcorder and it's probably 20 yrs. old.  I'm not holding my breath for a driver update at this point. :)  I might look for alternative drivers though.

Comment: Update to my post.

Comment: I tried another driver from Canon today and it didn't work.  Maybe you're right, but it sucks that there's not a solution for this.

Comment: So, I don't know if this is the solution or not (because I do still have this problem), but I'm going to mark it as the accepted answer because it appears to be right. :)

Comment: Thanks Mr John! :)